# Read Excel sheet data and convert each row as array of object using Typescript in React js

Tags: reactjs, excel, typescript

I am trying to read .xlsx file which is in my local project structure using Typescript in react and I want to convert the row as array of objec

[image]

**Expected output:**

{ "Segment": "Air", "TripName":"Test UI Flow", "startDate":"6/19/2020", "endDate":"6/25/2020", "totalFare":"3948" }

and soo on for each row. This is my implementation soo far but I am seeing undefined in data.

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const file = require("./copy.xlsx");
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (evt: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
      const arrayBuffer = evt.target?.result as ArrayBuffer;
      const wb = XLSX.read(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer), { type: "array" });
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, { FS: ",", RS: "\n" } as XLSX.Sheet2CSVOpts);
      console.log("Data>>>" + data);
      console.log(convertToJson(data));
    };
    const blob = new Blob([file.default], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error reading Excel file:", error);
  }
};

 fetchData();
}, []);

const convertToJson = (csv: string) => {
const lines = csv.split("\n");
const headers: string[] = lines[0].split(",");
const result = lines.slice(1).map((line) => {
  const currentline = line.split(",");
  const obj: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  headers.forEach((header, index) => {
    obj[header] = currentline[index];
  });
  return obj;
});
return JSON.stringify(result);
};
```